# Is it possible to model a dataset with Event > Non Event?

Tags: modeling

I have a dataset (30k), where Event = 82% and Non-Event= 18%, is it possible to use normal way of modeling (ie. regression/decisiontree/etc) to do a model (so far, i couldn't get a good result), or i should reverse the Event to 18% and Non event to 82% to do the modelling?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you evaluating the performance on your test set? Maybe you got high probabilities for every observation, with $p>1/2$ even for most of the $0$-entries, but they're still typically lower probability than the $1$s. In that case, something like an F1 measure would indicate poor results, yet a ranking-based metric like ROC or Lift curve might look good. Or a shift in your $p$-threshold when looking at things like F1, precision, or recall.

Comment: Let's say that each $i$ denotes a different day.. Are you asking if modeling whether it *did* rain on day $i$ is any different than modeling whether it *didn't* rain on day $i$?

Answer (score 1):

#### My understanding of your setting:

For observations $i=1, \ldots, n$ where $n \approx 30,000$ you have a binary variable $Y_i$ where:

$$Y_i = \left\{\begin{array}{rl}1 & \text{If event occurs} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{array} \right.$$

#### My understanding of your question:

Q: You're having trouble forecasting $Y_i$. Could you instead forecast $Z_i = 1 - Y_i$ (i.e. $Z_i = 1$ if the event *doesn't* occur).

A: For many standard methods: logistic regression, support vector machines, linear regression, etc... trying to forecast $Y$ or trying to forecast $Z$ will be entirely equivalent in the sense your forecasting power will be entirely the same.